# Eclipse IDE: How to stop Eclipse from opening .json files with Notepad, but with internal editor instead?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse with ADT for Android development and for some time now (about 2 weeks) the .json files that I store within the /raw folder are opened with Notepad instead of the internal editor.

How do I go back to opening those files with internal editor?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click over the file and choose "Open With > Text Editor" from the context menu.

Comment: I want this to happen when I double-click the file, like it used to

Comment: @J.K.: In that case, do what I wrote in my answer. Eclipse remembers the last setting you chose here, and so will do the same thing by default in the future.

Comment: well, I did it (Ive been doing this since the problem started) but Eclipse keeps opening them with Notepad at double click :(

Comment: @J.K.: The right-click only affects the file you right-click over. Eclipse remembers settings on a per-file basis. If you are seeing this behavior for a bunch of files by extension, go into Preferences > General > Content Types or Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations.

Comment: I added .json there but this didnt change anything